# How to calculate the probability of occurrences in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics, bayesian

I am working with three simple datasets and for reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ieC7eFuCz5KmtF6Ag-FtIkCAocDGQAGD).

To make it clear of what I am doing - from column 2, I am reading the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

protocols = {}

types = {"Data-V": "data_v.csv", "Data-R": "data_r.csv", "Data-C": "data_c.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    plt.plot(quotient_times, quotient, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("quotient_times")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

From this observation, I want to measure their probability (occurrence) at different `quotient_times`. Here is my approach

```
occurrence_count_data_v = 0
possibility_count_data_v = 0
occurrence_count_data_r = 0
possibility_count_data_r = 0
occurrence_count_data_c = 0
possibility_count_data_c = 0


if "data_v".lower() in fname:
    for index_v in range(len(quotient)):
        if quotient_times[index_v] < 3:
            possibility_count_data_v += 1
            if quotient[index_v] > 0.5:
                occurrence_count_data_v += 1

    probability_data_v = float(occurrence_count_data_v) / possibility_count_data_v
    print(fname, "=",probability_data_v)

elif "data_r".lower() in fname:
    for index_r in range(len(quotient)):
        if quotient_times[index_r] < 3:
            possibility_count_data_r += 1
            if quotient[index_r] == 0.5:
                occurrence_count_data_r += 1
    probability_data_r = float(occurrence_count_data_r) / possibility_count_data_r
    print(fname, "=", probability_data_r) 

elif "data_c".lower() in fname:
    for index_c in range(len(quotient)):
        if quotient_times[index_c] < 3:
            possibility_count_data_c += 1
            if quotient[index_c] == 0.7:
                occurrence_count_data_c += 1
    probability_data_c = float(occurrence_count_data_c) / possibility_count_data_c
    print(fname, "=",probability_data_c)
```

Output

> `data_v.csv = 1.0
>   data_r.csv = 1.0
>   data_c.csv = 1.0`

This means 100% of each data set where `quotient_times` is less than 3 also has a `quotient` of each data as specified above. However, this considers each data independently. How can we measure the occurrence of `quotient` for each data against the other? For example, when `quotient_times` is greater than 3 both `Data-V` and `Data-R` share the same `quotient` value of 5. How can we measure this occurence? Any help owuld be appreciated.